# Installed font not working

Tags: fonts, fontspec, templates

I have downloaded a latex template for a thesis from Harvard University.

Currently I'm using Linux Mint Nadia 14.

The instructions of the template tells you to install the needed fonts (which are included) with the command: `sudo cp fonts/* /usr/local/share/fonts/`
I have done so but I had to add to the command the flag `-r` in order to work properly.
When I try to compile the tex (using a compilation script also included which uses xelatex) I get the following error:

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "EB Garamond" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
```

EB Garamond is one of the fonts already installed by the previous command. I have also tried to execute `sudo fc-cache -fsv` from the cl. And I get in the output 
`/usr/local/share/fonts/EB Garamond: caching, new cache contents: 10 fonts, 0 dirs`

But the problem persists. Apparently it is a problem with permissions because it works with `sudo`. But changing the permissions of the font folders and files to 644 has not solved the problem either.

With this small example:

```
\fontfamily{EB Garamond}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

I get the following [logfile](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ujev69tgwgomi1o/dissertation.log)

Any idea?

Comment: run `fc-list | grep "EB Garamond"`. Does it lists the fonts? If yes, give a _complete_ example how you define the font setting.

Comment: @run Apparently is a problem of permissions. Because when I compile it with sudo everything works. I have changed the owner of "EB GARAMOND" folder to myself instead of root. And I have put permissions 755 to all the files in it. Still the problem persists,

Comment: Is it listed or not? However, for fonts use `644` as permission.

Comment: It is listed.

/usr/local/share/fonts/EB Garamond/EBGaramond12-SC.otf: EB Garamond,EB Garamond 12 SC:style=12 SC Regular,SC

/usr/local/share/fonts/EB Garamond/EBGaramond12-Regular.otf: EB Garamond,EB Garamond 12:style=12 Regular,Regular
....

Comment: @Herbert 644 with root or me as owner?

Comment: That makes no difference. I have _everything_ in `/usr/local/` _not_ as root, as long as it is a single user installation of Linux

Comment: Ok, it is listed. Then you have a wrong `\fontspec` or `\setmainfont` command. Show what you did!

Comment: @Herbert I don't think the problem is there. It is a template of Harvard University that works fine in my laptop. And it works fine with sudo.

Comment: have `/usr/local/share` and `/usr/local/share/fonts` 755 permission?

Comment: /usr/local/share has 755 (root owner).

/usr/local/share/fonts has that weird permissions with an s: drwxrwsr-x

Comment: Again: Create a small example and then show the logfile!

Comment: @Herbert thanks for your time. I have posted the log file in the question itself. I can't produce an small example, this is a large template for thesis.

Comment: That is _not_ the logfile, that is a snippet of it ... which doesn't help here. A small example starts with a document class `article` and loads EB Garamond. That's all!

Comment: @Herbert there you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
foo
\end{document}
```

run it with `xelatex` and then show the logfile if it fails. With

`pdffonts testfile.pdf` I get

```
name                         type        encoding    emb sub uni object ID
---------------------------- ----------- ----------- --- --- --- ---------
ZXTLQL+EBGaramond-Identity-H CID Type 0C Identity-H  yes yes yes      5  0
```

Comment: It fails, I dont get a pdf. The log file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vg8z0k8l0q5x3xy/example2.log

And again with sudo works, and I get the same output as you: MZZYTQ+EBGaramond12-Regular-Identity-H CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes      5  0

Comment: By setting 755 in all font folders and all its contents and keeping the S bit on in the permissions. It seems to work now. Really thanks for your time.